# Simplewallet shows zero balance after recovering XMR paper wallet (using Mac)

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, wallet-recovery, macos

I have made two paper wallets and can recover neither.

I use the Monero Test app to check balance once I have sent the Monero to the paper wallet (made with offline generator).

Then I launch simplewallet and use:

```
--restore-deterministic-wallet
```

When it asks, I put in the paper wallet seed, and recovery seemingly works OK, the address and view key etc match.

But when I type 'balance' it comes up zero...

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, or if I am somehow wiping the wallet balance during recovery (I have tried multiple times).  I sent small balances over - three XMR the first time, then 1.00 XMR the second time and cannot recover them. Both wallets I created and named Wallet 1, Wallet 2 in Simplewallet respectively, show up with balance 0.

I did `refresh` the entire blockchain too with the bitmonerod daemon open in another window and synched up.

Any thoughts on where the XMR are? I am totally loathe to do any larger transfers for obvious reasons.

I am losing sleep over having a lot of XMR on [MyMonero](https://mymonero.com/#/) - so was just testing this method of safe storage

EDIT - got some help from members of BTCT forum in Monero thread and it was due to the folders I had things in - the terminal and daemon are better in one folder with key files etc.  Then only open using command line direction to that folder.

Wait until bitmonerod is totally synchronised and then try refresh command.   All good now (and all XMR in safe offline created paper wallets) Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

After you use --restore-deterministic-wallet and the address loads correctly, type "refresh".

Answer (score 6):

You will probably need to rescan the blockchain, this can be done with the command

```
rescan_bc
```

It will take a while, also make sure you have a node running that simplewallet can talk to to do the refresh.

Comment: All good now thanks! But roll on the GUI - mac users may struggle with simplewallet and CLI working - I did, and I am not that stupid!